# How to simulate the key's pressing 'ENTER' in Python?

Tags: python, webdriver, key

From the image below, I want to simulate pressing the 'ENTER' or 'RETURN' key.

[image]

The html code for this is :

`<a href="javascript:doOuvrir(1350);">
    <img src="images/calendrier_plus.gif" bordercolor="#ff0000" valign="middle" title="Ouvrir prochaine semaine" alt="Ouvrir prochaine semaine" width="17" border="3" align="middle">
</a>`

In Python I wrote this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:doOuvrir(1350);']").click()
time.sleep(5) 
action.key_down(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

When it works correctly a new page opens but but in the current situation I have the following error message :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Projets\Hagrid\hagrid.py", line 65, in <module>
action.key_down(Keys.RETURN).perform()
File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
self.w3c_actions.perform()
File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\actions\action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Vous confirmez vouloir ouvrir une nouvelle semaine?
```

Could you, please, help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Catch exception and use `usedriver.switch_to.alert.accept()`

Comment: The error message is still present and the page that should appear still does not appear. Can you tell me more ?

Answer (score 0):

https://nitratine.net/blog/post/simulate-keypresses-in-python/

This link will help you out a lot, here's the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()


time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)

keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

`time.sleep` is optional

I don't check Stack Overflow much, so if you have a problem with this, visit the website or documentation for pynput: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#controlling-the-keyboard